# Does anyone know how to make/ identify this typography style?

Tags: technique-identification, style-identification

This design has been in my mind for a quite while. Do any of you know how to create/identify this kind of typography? I need some help because this kind of design intrigued me a lot.

[image]
<sub>*Source unidentifiable*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts, it's good to have you! "Identification" and "how-to-make" are two different questions. Are you interested in answers about how to make this kind of thing, or are you interested in questions about what it's called and the role it plays in the art world?

Comment: A few things in addition to what Matt asked. 1. Please credit the source of the image (required under the Creative Commons licensing the platform uses).  2. Different people may focus on different aspects of the art and think the question is asking about different things. To get answers that address what you want to know, it would help to clarify what are the important aspects to you. One way would be with several different images that have the important aspects in common. Another would be to describe the elements that are and are not important. (cont'd)

Comment: For example, this looks like cut-out letters in different styles superimposed on a blurry photographic background of people. Does it make a difference whether the background is blurry, photographic, or what its subject is? Is anything about the styles, color, content, size, etc. of the letters important, or just that they're various mixed styles that look like they were cut from different sources? Does single letters vs. words or explicit message make a difference? Is the "messy" orientation and positioning of the letters important? (cont'd)

Comment: Many of those kinds of questions wouldn't affect the "how to create it" part, but it could affect the style identification. 3. Where did you see this, and do you know what format and size the original is? That could answer whether this was made as a collage of a photo and cut-out letters vs. something made digitally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're only talking about the (mix of) typography, since that is the feature jumping out, this is actually known as the [ransom note effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransom_note_effect):

> In typography, **the ransom note effect is the result of using an excessive number of juxtaposed typefaces**. It takes its name from the appearance of a stereotypical ransom note, with the message formed from words or letters cut randomly from a magazine or newspaper in order to avoid using recognizable handwriting.

Comment: I'm surprised the definition doesn't include the random alignment and spacing, which is normal for this effect and shown well in the example given

Comment: @ChrisH Good point. It's maybe partially insinuated by talking about the *juxtaposition*, specifically :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific name for this typography style. But there are several alternatives to find results in Google. The main one is [Kidnap Font](https://www.google.com/search?q=kidnapp%20typography%20style&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&oq=kidnapp%20typography%20style&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390l4.11408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

As a graphical alternative, you will find many results in [Mixed Message Font](https://www.google.com/search?q=mixed%20messages%20typography&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjsrc2nu679AhVaZqQEHax8AdQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=mixed%20messages%20typography&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoGCAAQCBAeOgcIABCABBAYOgYIABAHEB5QjghYvBJguxVoAHAAeACAAXmIAd4GkgEDOS4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=Xdb4Y6yLG9rMkdUPrPmFoA0&bih=1208&biw=1533&rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507).

Answer (score -1):

I would not call it really a "typography style", as it is a random collection of styles.

However, from an artistic POV, I would call it a [**collage**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collage). It is a collection of cropped pictures, each picture containing a letter (or other symbol) with various type settings.